# Not receiving push notifications when enterprise app is in production

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have created an application on an enterprise account, since it's just going to be used by the employees in the company,
I have made the provisioning profiles and the certificates, while the app is still in development, I can receive push notifications normally, sandbox = 1, but when we added the app to the website, push notifications are not been received, knowing that the sandbox turned to 0. [image]
Any idea what could be wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the certificate that you are using to send the notifications is attached to a "Distribution Provisioning Profile" and not "Development Provisioning Profile".

Got to `iTunes Connect > Identifiers > App IDs`, and make sure that your App ID Push Notifications are configured for Distribution. **AND** you are using the matching certificate when sending the notifications.

[image]

Comment: i did that, but the certificate gave an error on the server side : unable to coonect : tls:W gateway.push.apple.com:2195:2 (stream_socket_client():Unable to set private key file